# JUnit AsserEquals() failing because of extra whitespace on array

Tags: java, junit

A Junit test of mine is failing when comparing 2 arrays with kafka producer records in them. The failure is one extra space after the array.

Expected:

```
java.util.ArrayList<[ProducerRecord(topic=producer-test, partition=null, 
headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key=0, 
value=Message: test-message,
Number: 0, timestamp=null), ProducerRecord(topic=producer-test, 
partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), 
key=1, value=Message: test-message,
Number: 1, timestamp=null)]>
```

Actual:

```
java.util.ArrayList<[ProducerRecord(topic=producer-test, partition=null, 
headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key=0, 
value=Message: test-message,
Number: 0, timestamp=null), ProducerRecord(topic=producer-test, 
partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), 
key=1, value=Message: test-message,
Number: 1, timestamp=null)]>
```

The IDE tells me that the only difference is one space after the end of the arrayList in Expected, which you can see by highlighting the end. What is going on?!

Edit:

Here is some of the other code

```
List<ProducerRecord<Integer, TestObj>> history = producer.history();

    //To be inserted into expected
    TestObj obj0 = new TestObj("test-message", 0);
    TestObj obj1 = new TestObj("test-message", 1);

    //new arraylist is needed or else the lists have slightly different types for some reason
    List<ProducerRecord<Integer, TestObj>> expected = new ArrayList<ProducerRecord<Integer, TestObj>>(Arrays.asList(
            new ProducerRecord<Integer, TestObj>("producer-test", 0, obj0),
            new ProducerRecord<Integer, TestObj>("producer-test", 1, obj1)
    ));

    Assert.assertEquals("Sent didn't match expected!", expected, history);
```

Comment: Is the expected output a constant? Why can't you remove the trailing space in it?

Comment: I am just inserting an array into the expected and actual, and the test fails every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Assert.assertEquals()` is invoking `expected.equals(history)`

The definition for `List.equals(Object o)` is the following:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.

Have you defined an `equals` method for your ProducerRecord class?

If you have not, then your `ProducerRecord` objects will be compared by reference equality, meaning that they will only be compared on the basis if they are actually the same objects. Since you are constructing new `ProducerRecord` objects within your test, they will not have reference equality.

Comment: The ProducerRecord is an object that comes with kafka; I double checked and it indeed has an equals() function, the only difference my IDE tells me there is is that little space at the end of expected.

Comment: Can you confirm that something like 

`(new ProducerRecord<Integer, TestObj>("producer-test", 0, obj0)).equals(new ProducerRecord<Integer, TestObj>("producer-test", 0, obj0))` is true?

Also does your `TestObj` override `equals()`?

Comment: It turned out that ProducerRecord had an equals(), but was failing because I didn't have an equals() for my testObj.

Comment: This helped me when using Lombok Builder. In addition to builder I also needed @EqualsAndHashCode.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two objects or two list of objects, you can override (equals) method of that object and compare all the elements of that object there. If all of them match, you can return true for equal. Check example below:

```
public class Customer {
String name;
int age;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj)
        return true;

    // it checks if the argument is of the type Customer by comparing the classes
    // of the passed argument and this object.
    // if(!(obj instanceof Customer)) return false; ---> avoid.
    if(obj == null || obj.getClass()!= this.getClass())
        return false;

    // type casting of the argument.
    Customer customer = (Customer) obj;
    if(customer.getName().equals(this.name) &&
            (customer.getAge() == this.age))
        return true;

    return false;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```